# How to specify output.classesDir for custom sourceSet in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, jar

My build uses source code from two projects: ProjectA and ProjectB, and produces JAR with classes and resources from ProjectB. I defined custom sourceSet mainProjectB which is supposed to have output in a separate directory:

```
sourceSets {
    mainProjectB {
        output.classesDir = "$buildDir/build/classes/projectB"
        output.resourcesDir = "$buildDir/build/resources/projectB"
        java { srcDirs = ['src/main/java']}
        resources { srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']}
    }
    mainProjectA {
        java { srcDirs = [
                '../projectA/src/main/java'
            ]}
        resources { srcDirs = [
                '../projectA/src/main/resources'
            ]}
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = [
                '../projectA/src/test/java',
                'src/test/java'
            ]}
        resources {
            srcDirs = [
                '../projectA/src/test/resources',
                'src/test/resources'
            ]}
    }
}

compileJava {
    source sourceSets.mainProjectB.allJava
    source sourceSets.mainProjectA.allJava
}

processResources {
    from sourceSets.mainProjectB.resources
    from sourceSets.mainProjectA.resources
}

jar {
    from sourceSets.mainProjectB.output.classesDir
    from sourceSets.mainProjectB.output.resourcesDir
}
```

Problem: custom sourceSet mainProjectB ingores specified output directories.
The directories "$buildDir/build/classes/projectB" and "$buildDir/build/resources/projectB" are not created, and as a consequence, JAR includes files from both projects (instead of ProjectB).

UPDATE:
Projects A and B have circular dependencies. That is why they have to share source code.

Comment: Are you trying to make a jar that merges the contents of projectA and projectB?

Comment: No: JAR with classes and resources from ProjectB

Answer (score 1):

I would consider to use subprojects and project to achieve your goal - [gradel docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#javadependencies_2) . With the following approach you can get any kind of jar file depending on your build :

```
group 'CoreProject'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

project (':projectA') {

}

project (':projectB') {
    def generatedResources = "$buildDir"
    //in case you want resources and classes to be written to custom location where 
    //redefined paths are relative to projectB root folder 
    sourceSets {
        main {
            output.classesDir = 'build/classes/projectB'
            output.resourcesDir = 'build/resources/projectB'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile project(':projectA')
    }
    jar {
        manifest.mainAttributes(
                'Main-Class': "ProjectBClass"
        )
    }

    //To create fat Jar that will contain classes and resources from all dependencies
    task fatJar(type: Jar) {
        manifest.from jar.manifest
        classifier = 'all'
        from {
            configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        } {
            exclude "ProjectAResource" //if want to exclude resources from projectA
            exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
            exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
            exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
        }
        with jar
    }
}
```

If you run **jar task** of projectB following jars will be created, each including only its own classes and resources : **projectA/build/libs/projectA.jar** , **projectB/build/libs/projectB.jar**('*JAR with classes and resources from ProjectB*' as you asked in your comment)

If you run **farJar task** of projectB the following jar file will be created that includes classes and resources from both projects and you can exclude any files patterns from projectA and projectB projects to create any final jar you like : **projectB/build/libs/projectB-all.jar**

Here is a screenshot of projects folders structure I created to mimic your scenario(as I understood it):
[image]

P.S. Also make sure none of the folders projectB/build and projectA/build are locked by any process and remove those handles if any, as otherwise Gradle will fail to run.

Comment: Projects A and B have circular dependencies. That is why they have to share source code, so your approach will not work for my use case.

Comment: doesn't work with Gradle 5, classesDir has been deprecated